# 3D polylines, recieving z-value as attribute in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, attribute-table, 3d

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop, and attempting to create a runoff mode for a water course and the surrounding floodplain.

I have depth data in the form of contours, given as 3D-polylines. Each line has an attibute which shows the depth at each line but i need the z-value instead since i need to merge the depth contours with an existing elevation model outside of the water course. In order to do that i have to have the elevation as an attribute (a z-field in the attibute table) for each line. How can give each line the Z-value as an attribute?

When i extract the vertices i use add xy-data which gives me the z-value. I wish to do something similar but for the polylines. Each lines has only one z-value assigned to it which is clear when reviewing the z-value in each vertex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Add Z Information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-z-information.htm). For lines you can choose between minimum, maximum and mean Z, which should all be equivalent in your case if the lines have only oneZ.